# Migration from MariaDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, migration, mariadb, database-migration

We need to move a db from MariaDB to MySQL db but are having trouble finding any documentation about this. Does anyone have any experience doing this?

We currently have multiple dbs in MySQL and are trying to add a relatively small one from MariaDB which is why it has to happen like this rather than the other way around.

Comment: MariaDB is mostly a "drop-in replacement for MySQL".  Try it; ask for help if you have some specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following MariaDB documentation link, which discusses in detail the compatibility issues between various versions of MariaDB and MySQL:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

There is a useful matrix which shows compatibility between versions at a glance.